# My wifi only allow me to use http with proxy-auth, can I use other program which use other protocol?

Tags: http, tcpip, http-proxy

My school offers students WiFi which only able to use browser or other program which use only http and support proxy-authentication with BASIC Auth. For other program such as windows live messenger, outlook, skype, torrent or online games cannot be used.

How can I use the other program with this wifi?

PS. My WiFi use proxy authentication with BASIC Auth.

Comment: Your best bet would be to ask the network administrators how to use the the service for torrents.  You'll probably find it is against policy, and there are mechanisms in place to prevent services other than http/https.

Comment: @Paul that is why I ask here, because my network administrators want to block the students from using non-http application. But now I understands that it could not be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give [proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/) a try, it allows applications that don't usually use proxies to use them.